# Add optional OID in CMS/PKCS 7 signature in C# and Compact Framework 3.5

Tags: c#, cryptography, openssl, compact-framework

By using CAPI functions (in C# and Compact Framework 3.5), I try to sign a XML and create an CMS/PKCS envelop like the following OpenSSL command do:

```
openssl smime -sign -in file.xml -out file.b64 -passin pass:test -binary -nodetach -inkey cert.priv.pem -signer cert.pub.pem
```

By calling the functions "CryptMsgOpenToEncode" and "CryptMsgUpdate", I obtain a first signed file. Now I would add optional OID and others datas (more precisely the "SMIMECapabilities", and signing time).

How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I've got similar problem. I found this post, where is recomended to use  Certificate Enrollment API.

Bouncy Castle is also capable of writing SMIMECapabilities.

Update:
Content of the original link: 
As far as I know, there is not support for the SMIMECapabilities property in .NET, for touching this property, the IX509CertificateRequestPkcs10::SmimeCapabilities in Certificate Enrollment API seems to be support it, you could check it:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa377586(v=vs.85).aspx

Additional info:
After some research I was able to write SMIMECapabilities using CmsSigner (I am creating signed document in detached state). 
I use this code.

```
signer.SignedAttributes.Add(new AsnEncodedData("1.2.840.113549.1.9.15",  new byte[]{...})
```

Unfortunatly CmsSigner can write content of SMIMECapabilities only as byte array. I used this tool https://lapo.it/asn1js/ to decode file with sign created in openssl to find out correct byte array.